# Post form data and sending it using mail - php

Tags: php, encoding, email

I have some troubles with encoding and mailing.
I send post-request to php-script, when I do

```
print_r( $_POST );
```

I could see my text normally, but when I'm trying to send it into email, using code:

```
$text = ...; // Includeing data from $_POST;
    $headers  = "From: test\r\n";
    $headers .= "Return-Path: test\r\n";
    $headers .= 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\n";
    $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
mail( 'my@email.com', 'Посылка от формы контактов', $text, $headers )
```

Yes, mail's theme is in cyryllical. So, when I get mail I see something like:

```
Здравствуйте!
На сайте была заполнена форма контактов:
Наименование организации: РќР°РёРјРµРЅРѕРІР°РЅРёРµ РѕСЂРіР°РЅРёР·Р°С†РёРё
Контактное лицо: РљРѕРЅС‚Р°РєС‚РЅРѕРµ Р»РёС†Рѕ
Телефон: РўРµР»РµС„РѕРЅ
E-mail: РёРјРµР№Р»
На тему: Р—Р°РјРµС‡Р°РЅРёСЏ РїРѕ СЂР°Р±РѕС‚Рµ СЃР°Р№С‚Р°
С‚РµРєСЃС‚ СЃРѕРѕР±С‰РµРЅРёСЏ
```

But subject and another text, which I'm adding in send-script is readable.

What is my problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cyrillic alphabet is contained within the following charset:

```
charset=iso-8859-5
```

You could try and change your charset.  I'm really up in the air on this one but I thought I'd try to help.

For a longer listing of charsets, visit [here](http://a4esl.org/c/charset.html)

Comment: When I applyed that encoding, I can't even seen that text I've posted in script.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your file including the email's text is using the proper encoding.